# Paste Special from Excel to Powerpoint on Mac Office

Tags: excel, vba, macos, powerpoint

My code worked perfectly on Windows but not on MacBook. I need to copy a range of cells to Powerpoint and still, it should be editable so I only need to copy the texts. PasteSpecial does not seems to work on Mac office. What worked in Mac is copying the range of cells as a picture and pasting it to powerpoint as an image. This should not be the case because the pasted shape should be editable. My code below Please help.

```
{
Opening PPT and creating a new presentation
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add
    
    'Add and select new slide
    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
    ppSlide.Select
    
    'Copy range from excel sheet
    Sheets("ToPPT").Range("rng_Picture").Copy
    DoEvents
    
    'Paste range as html
    Set shp = ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteHTML)
    
    With ppPres.PageSetup
        shp.Width = .SlideWidth
        shp.Height = .SlideHeight
    End With
    
    'adjust position in slide
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignTops, msoTrue
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignLefts, msoTrue
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac there is no PasteSpecial in this situation.
Yo can check this by writing the code line on the Mac.
I used just PASTE and got the cells in there - maybe this is good enough and then you can format them further.

Comment: thank you for your response G.N. but how can I further format a pasted picture?

Comment: When I test that I get the table pasted as table, not as picture. That means when you copied it was already not a table format? Can you provide us with screenshots?

Comment: @ErnestRyanCepeda you never answered. If don't mind, be so nice and mark my answer as correct.